# Javascript Msxml2.XMLHTTP terminal server access denied

Tags: javascript, access-denied, msxml, activexobject, terminal-services

var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://vat/_vti_bin/lists.asmx", false);

How can I let this script work on a Terminal server? When I open it on my local pc, it works, but when I do the same thing in a browser on a Terminal server, I get `Access Denied`.

I tried using `ServerXMLHTTP`, but then i get `Cannot create automation object`

Answer (score 0):

Is `vat` your local pc or the terminal server? I'm guessing it's your local pc, which means you'll be limited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) - this means you can only make a request from the same server the page is being served from.

You can get around this using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), which - in a nutshell - loads the ajax as a script tag with a js callback.

Or just move your ajax feed onto your web server.

Comment: VAT is the server ( cit-srv-004.Converge-IT.local is dns name ).
Dns name Terminal server is ( cit-srv-003.Converge-IT.local ).

But it works in my browser on local pc, I get access denied  when I do the same in the browser on Terminal server desktop.

Comment: Change your request to point to `/_vti_bin/lists.asmx` (ie no hostname)

Comment: That might be, but that's the problem. Your request needs to originate from the same hostname as the website, or it will be restricted by SOP.

Comment: But why don't I have that problem when I do this from a browser on my local pc, 

I'm calling a script from http:/crm/ and I post data to http:/vat/_vti_bin/lists.asmx

Comment: Could you just try it and see?

Comment: Changed my request to point to /_vti_bin/lists.asmx. I get statuscode 500 or Internal Server Error. Now it goes to http:/crm/../_vti_bin/lists.asmx, but I need to go to http:/vat/vti_bin/lists.asmx.